# Vue3 second level objects properties are undefined

Tags: object, vuejs3, undefined

This is my code

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref,reactive } from "@vue/reactivity";
import { onMounted } from "@vue/runtime-core";
import axios from "axios";
import 'vue3-carousel/dist/carousel.css';
import { Carousel, Slide, Pagination, Navigation } from 'vue3-carousel';

    const maps = ref(null)
    const api_key = import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY
    onMounted(async ()=>{
        if (sessionStorage.getItem("maps") === null) {
            await axios.get(`https://api.mozambiquehe.re/maprotation?version=5&auth=${api_key}`).then((res) => {
                maps.value = res.data
                sessionStorage.setItem('maps', JSON.stringify(res.data))
                spinner.value= false
            })
        }
        else{
            maps.value = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("maps")!)
            spinner.value= false
        }
    })
    const spinner = ref(true);
</script>
<template>
    <div class="relative">
        <div class="text-center absolute inset-0 z-50 bg-white" :class="{'hidden': !spinner}">
            <div role="status">
                <svg class="inline mr-2 w-8 h-8 text-gray-200 animate-spin dark:text-gray-600 fill-blue-600" viewBox="0 0 100 101" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M100 50.5908C100 78.2051 77.6142 100.591 50 100.591C22.3858 100.591 0 78.2051 0 50.5908C0 22.9766 22.3858 0.59082 50 0.59082C77.6142 0.59082 100 22.9766 100 50.5908ZM9.08144 50.5908C9.08144 73.1895 27.4013 91.5094 50 91.5094C72.5987 91.5094 90.9186 73.1895 90.9186 50.5908C90.9186 27.9921 72.5987 9.67226 50 9.67226C27.4013 9.67226 9.08144 27.9921 9.08144 50.5908Z" fill="currentColor"/>
                    <path d="M93.9676 39.0409C96.393 38.4038 97.8624 35.9116 97.0079 33.5539C95.2932 28.8227 92.871 24.3692 89.8167 20.348C85.8452 15.1192 80.8826 10.7238 75.2124 7.41289C69.5422 4.10194 63.2754 1.94025 56.7698 1.05124C51.7666 0.367541 46.6976 0.446843 41.7345 1.27873C39.2613 1.69328 37.813 4.19778 38.4501 6.62326C39.0873 9.04874 41.5694 10.4717 44.0505 10.1071C47.8511 9.54855 51.7191 9.52689 55.5402 10.0491C60.8642 10.7766 65.9928 12.5457 70.6331 15.2552C75.2735 17.9648 79.3347 21.5619 82.5849 25.841C84.9175 28.9121 86.7997 32.2913 88.1811 35.8758C89.083 38.2158 91.5421 39.6781 93.9676 39.0409Z" fill="currentFill"/>
                </svg>
                <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <pre>{{maps}}</pre>
        <div>
            <h2 class="text-2xl font-bold dark:text-white mb-5">Battle Royale</h2>
            <carousel :items-to-show="1" :wrapAround="true" v-if="!spinner">
                <slide v-for="slide in 10" :key="slide">
                    <div class="duration-700 ease-in-out" data-carousel-item>
                        <img :src="maps.battle_royale.asset" class="w-full h-[380px] rounded-lg object-cover" alt="...">
                        <div class="flex flex-wrap my-5">
                            <p class="mr-auto px-2">{{maps.battle_royale.map}}</p>
                            <p class="mr-auto px-2">Duration: {{maps.battle_royale.DurationInMinutes}} Minutes</p>
                            <p class="px-2">Remaining: {{maps.battle_royale.remainingMins}} Minutes</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </slide>
                <template #addons>
                    <pagination/>
                </template>
            </carousel>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I defined maps as null and called the API to set maps value then I rendered the carousel. If the value is found in session storage it won't call API simply it will get the value from the session. When I used maps in the template it showed the whole JSON data, but when I used the second-level properties like maps.battle_royale in the template it was undefined.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to review my question. I'm very very sorry there is nothing wrong with my code, API is the issue. Now it's sorted out and it's working.